# I want to use non-consumable and auto renewable So,Is it possible to use 2 IAP products in one App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

In My App I have used non-consumable IAP while Login.
and I want to use Auto-renewable subscription for Remove Ad feature.

So, Will it be any chance of rejection from Apple or Is this a valid to use multiple product in one App?

Comment: You can use different types of IAP in the one app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible but for that you have to create two group in your developer portal. For same group you can't purchase two IAP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use multiple IAP same time.
There might be a problem If your both active IAPs provide the same features.
Apple might reject it.